# I cannot add in a List

Tags: java

I have next code:

```
List<String> str=Arrays.asList("cat","tiger","dog","mouse");
str.add("horse");
```

It compiles, but at runtime I have UnsupportedOperationException.  Why does it happen?

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.asList(String...)` creates an unmodifiable array. Wrap it with another `ArrayList` like so:

```
List<String> str = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("cat","tiger","dog","mouse"));
str.add("horse");
```

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.asList()` returns a list that is [fixed-size and backed by the array you pass](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) so you can't add or remove elements because that would mean changing the array as well. (note that if you have a look at the source you'll find that `Arrays.asList()` will return an instance of `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` which you should not confuse with `java.util.ArrayList` which you probably already know).

Instead you'd need to create another list, e.g via calling `new ArrayList<String>( Arrays.asList(...))` which effectively makes a copy of the passed list.

A Java 8+ way might be this:

```
List<String> str = Stream.of( "cat","tiger","dog","mouse" ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

Comment: When you say  java.util.Arrays.ArrayList is as this ArrayList is a nested class of Arrays, but I don't see so.  The method Arrays.asList() return a java.util.List, no java.util.Arrays.ArrayList.

Comment: @JoseNg no, the method's signature states it will return something that extends or implements `List` (i.e. the interface is returned) but the actual implementation will be `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` - just have a look at the source (I can't find a link to a current source repo but here's the method body of `Arrays.asList(...)` right from my IDE: `return new ArrayList<>(a);`).

Answer (score 0):

this called backed list . 
backed list it's created when you convert an array to list but keep in your mind the element in the array is linked with the element in the list so you cant add or delete any thing and you are using varargs its similar to array ,